# Unable to solve "The type name 'Models' does not exist in the type 'NotificationApp'" Error after some command execution

Tags: asp.net-core

I was running command below:

```
 dotnet new page -n Index -na myapp.Pages.Area -o Pages/Area
 ns=-na=myapp.Pages
 dotnet new page -n Index $ns.Area -o Pages/Area
```

And it eventually caused the error:

> Views/_ViewImports.cshtml(1,7): error CS0138: A 'using namespace'
>   directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'NotificationApp' is a
>   type not a namespace. Consider a 'using static' directive instead
>   [/home/seocliff/Desktop/dotNetProjects/NotificationApp/NotificationApp.csproj]`

Now everytime I run `dotnet build` or `dotnet run` above error keeps appearing. Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the namespace lines within `_ViewImports.cshtml`:

```
@using  NotificationApp
@using  NotificationApp.Models
```

I also removed related files to "ErrorViewModel", like the following:

**ErrorViewModel.cs** within `Views/Home/Shared`

**Error.cshtml** within `Views/Home/Shared`

Also I had temporarily commented **Error** Action Method:

```
// public IActionResult Error()
// {
//     return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
// }
```

Then I run `dotnet build` and then launch the app again with `dotnet run`. It all worked out well. I will further investigate how it cause this issue as I unable to find a proper answer